# Django. How to put posts in a for loop where each post has a like button and show a dislike button if the user already liked the post?

Tags: django, ajax

I am trying to print out blog posts in a for loop and allow users to like the post. How do I show a dislike button if the user already liked the post? When I try put the like section template into the for loop every button is set to "Like" even if the user already liked the post.

views.py

```
def view_post(request, id=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=post.author.id)
    userProfile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user.pk)
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'post': post, 
        'userProfile': userProfile,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
    }
return render(request, "post/post.html", context)

def like_post(request, id=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
    is_liked = False
    if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
        post.likes.remove(request.user)
        is_liked = False
    else:
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        is_liked = True
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'is_liked': is_liked,
    }
    if request.is_ajax():
        html = render_to_string('like_section.html', context, request=request)
return JsonResponse({'form': html})
```

like template

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
      {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

AJAX

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(event){

    $(document).on('click', '#like', function(event){
      console.log("i'm clicked");
      event.preventDefault();
      var pk = $(this).attr('value');
      var url = "/post/like/";

    // Construct the full URL with "id"
    var theUrl = url + pk;
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: theUrl,
        data: {post_id: pk, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){
          $('#'+pk).html(response['form'])
          console.log($('#'+pk).html(response['form']));
        },
        error: function(rs, e){
          console.log(rs.responseText);
        },
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you please share your loop?

Comment: {% for post in posts %}
      <a href="/post/{{post.id}}/"><p>"{{ post.title }}"</a></p></a>
                <div id="{{post.id}}">
                    {% include 'like_section.html' %} 
                </div>
            {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is quite simple, you're including the template without any instance. You you are trying to access `is_liked` which doesn't exist. So you're always getting the else section (= Like).

Try instead to handover the post instance to the template by using `with` ([see the include docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#include)):

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <a href="/post/{{post.id}}/"><p>"{{ post.title }}"</p></a>
    <div id="{{post.id}}"> {% include 'like_section.html' with post=post %} </div>
{% endfor %}
```

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <form action="" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {% if post.is_liked %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-danger">Dislike</button>
      {% else %}
        <button type="submit" id="like" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Like</button>
      {% endif %}
    </form>
{% endif %}
```